# Xamarin Android QR Scanner application

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I have to read QR Code from the camera and display the result on the textview using xamarin android. For this I have researched in google and found the below two links:

- https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/xamarin-android-qr-code-reader-by-mobile-camera/
- https://varunrathore.wordpress.com/2015/03/24/105/

But I need to display the camera inside 4 square braces. I searched for examples but couldn't found.

How to place the camera inside the certain area as shown in the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: i have tried this https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/xamarin-android-qr-code-reader-by-mobile-camera/ but i am getting  'Resource.Drawable' does not contain a definition for 'qrcode' at line Bitmap bitMap = BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(ApplicationContext
            .Resources, Resource.Drawable.qrcode);

Comment: Can try clean and rebuild project.

Comment: We use zxing lib and qrview. Zhis view you can insert in ohter layout.